# Does C++ not allow you to call private functions from the constructor?

Tags: c++

I have the following program

```
#include <iostream>

class Blah {
    private:
        void hello();  
    public:
        Blah();  
};

void Blah::hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world" << std::endl;
}

Blah::Blah() {
    hello();
}

int main() {
    Blah a();
    return 0;
}
```

it compiles fine, but when I run it, the program does not print "Hello, world" into the console as I would have expected. Why is this?

Comment: Once again... And again... and again... and again... (and this is **not** the MVP.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Blah a();
```

This doesn't create an object, it declares a function. Change it to

```
Blah a;
```

This is sometimes known as a "vexing parse".